# Weird loop while reading FileInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, loops, java-stream

While debugging some code, I have noticed that my while loop doesn't finish. It just gets stuck?

Only way to fix it was to add `System.out.println(fis.read(buffer));` into the loop.

This is the loop

```
        while(fis.read(buffer) > 0) {
        System.out.println(fis.read(buffer));
        dos.write(buffer);
        }
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?
Do I need to invoke fis.read in the loop?

Comment: You're reading twice per iteration...

Comment: Ik that I'm doing that. But without the second read the loop just gets stuck..

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to do:

```
while (fis.read(buffer) != -1) {
    System.out.println(buffer);
    dos.write(buffer);
}
```

You are caling `read` method multiple times and as per javadoc, it blocks until some input is available (that's why the program hangs). This is what javadoc says:

> Reads up to b.length bytes of data from this input stream into an
>   array of bytes. This method blocks until some input is available.

Comment: Thank you for the better while loop, but I figured out the problem. It was due to the server not saving the file...